# Failed to query active directory groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, mdm, usergroups, airwatch

I have a problem with the synchronization of active directory groups with MDM,
The user/password is correct, it is marked so it never expires. Looking at the logs I see the following error:

2016/12/21 07:25:32.433 CSWAIRWZ11  8e66e0df-00a6-4997-a293-bccd713e430c    [0000000-0000000]   (52)    Error   WanderingWiFi.AirWatch.BusinessImpl.EnterpriseIntegrationHelper.SearchGroups    Directory call failed. System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException:80090311: LdapErr: DSID-0C0905DE, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 51f, v1db1 Error code:49

Besides the user / password, what other problem could happen?

Thank you very much in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

LDAP Error code 49 means AD_INVALID CREDENTIALS ([source](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes#gsc.tab=0)).

Are you sure that the AD credentials of the account you are using to bind with your Domain Controller are correct? If yes, then I would try using some alternative bind authentication types supported by AirWatch. In my experience Basic and GSS-Negotiate work the best.

If this still does not work, then install an LDAP client on your console server (like for example [LDP.exe](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/w2k3/utilities/ldp.htm)) and make sure you can bind with your account.

Hope this helps!